# Content at header

Tags: html, css

Tried to make content at center, played around with the position. but the content is still at the header.

Content:

```
<div id="content">
    <img class="left" src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/android-boot-logo_634639.jpg" width="200" height="287" alt="" />Et harumd dereud facilis est er expedit distinct. Et harumd dereud facilis est er expedit distinct. Yoii rockem sockem mow-em yown. Manarie li que vaqeriao. Occae et harumb bet theap. Est praesent luptatum. Ha! Bis nostrud exercitation ullam mmodo consequet. Duis aute in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. At vver eos et accusam dignissum qui blandit est praesent luptatum delenit aigue excepteur sint occae. Et harumd dereud facilis est er expedit distinct.
</div>
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/cfr7m6h4/

Comment: you can wrap your text in <p> and give class to align center

Comment: Using **floats** makes your work *far harder* than it needs to be. Using positioning/display properties instead will make your implementation far easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
position: relative;
```

instead of

```
position: fixed;
```

I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cfr7m6h4/4/